# how to successfully post all values from for each loop to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

i am creating a form where that has two text fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="itemname[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["name"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="itemprice[]" id="text-basic" value="<?php echo $item["price"]; ?>">
```

they both have [] enclosed to their name attributes because i want to post multiple values from them.

now i am trying to post the values of this textfields into my database column 'order' as one with this for each loop below

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['itemname'], $_POST['itemprice']) as $name => $email) {
 echo $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
  $mine = $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (name, orders)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$mine')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
```

but it only posts the last value of the array, meaning if three values where to be submitted only the last one goes, but if i echo it all three shows.
 please why am i having this issue, anyone?

Comment: put your query in your loop

Comment: thanks, please may i ask why my question is been marked down

Comment: like this ? foreach (array_combine($_POST['itemname'], $_POST['itemprice']) as $name => $email) {
 echo $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
  $mine = $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (name, orders)
VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$mine')";
}

Comment: can u please advice on how to properly arrange my query in my statement to derive the result i want

Comment: sorry that leaves me with an sql syntax error

Comment: post name is the name of the person fill in the form

Comment: i get this when i do a dump string(1) "w"

Comment: A good rule of thumb is NEVER execute a query inside a loop. Instead, build the query inside the loop. Close the loop. Execute the query. And it makes no sense to be storing the this data in this way.

Comment: @ strawberry how would u have me store this data, pls advice

Answer (score 0):

try this one .

Put Insert Statement inside your loop.

```
<?php

foreach (array_combine($_POST['itemname'], $_POST['itemprice']) as $name => $email) {
  echo $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
  $mine = $name . " - " . $email . "<br />";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (name, orders) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$mine')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: thanks but i still get an sql syntax error there for escaping the '

Comment: thanks this works in the sense that it posts the values into two diff rows what i want to do is post the values of the for each loop into a column, column 'orders'

Comment: so i will have only one record with all the values posted as an array

Comment: why is nobody pointing out the obvious sql injection vulnerability here?

Comment: @hanshenrik, you already did :) As long as someone mentions it then it keeps it current.